# Azure Data Factory - Data Flow - Run SQL User-Defined Function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a Scalar-Valued function stored in a database on Azure SQL Managed Instance. When I run queries/stored-procs on the database, I can obviously directly run this function.

But now I need to move my SQL loads to Azure Data Factory data flows. I could not find a way to call the user-defined functions from the ADF data flow. I thought I could use SELECT transformation to call this function the same way we do it on the database query but looks like that can't be done. By any chance, would anybody have an idea about how to call this function from the data flow?

Comment: I'm curious - why do you need to move your SQL loads to Azure Data Factory data flows? If you have a lot of SQL native functionality this is going to be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the User-defined function from dataflow source transformation.

I have a scalar user defined function created on Azure SQL.

[image]

In **Azure Data factory dataflow**, connect the source to Azure SQL database and in Source options, select Input as Query and call the function by using Select to get the data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Niharika! I would need to pass a few parameters to my function. These parameter values are generated during the data flow transformation steps. Can I still use the Source transformation for calling this function?

Comment: You can use another source in dataflow, Can you explain your scenario more? Also can you please share a screenshot of your dataflow for better understanding?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT I have this same use case asked in this question. If you are able to help it would be a tremendous help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71684052/how-to-pass-a-dynamic-parameter-as-sql-query-in-azure-data-flow