# How to pass a dynamic parameter as SQL query in Azure Data Flow?

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I am trying to run dynamic queries with a parameter in Azure Data Flow but I continue to get the "Column operands are not allowed in literal expressions" error. The parameter value is "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column in ('D1234','D1234','D1234','D8585','D6565','D7777','D4949','D2066','D2259','D5432')". I have tried all the ways to enter this parameter value, "{$parameter1}", {$parameter1}, $parameter1, ($parameter1) and I still continue to get the frustratying error. I have looked at all the documentation and forums relating to this issue but all of them continue to suggest the same ways I have tried to enter the value and none of it works. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated[image: My parameter in the query]

Answer (score 0):

you can make pipeline parameters and use them in query and You can make your query using Expressions.

```
@concat('Select * from fn_getDetails (',pipeline().parameters.empId,')')
```

Hope it helps you.